# Pre-loading interstitial ads - what is the max time(minutes) they can be cache before shown?

Tags: admob

Like [`Facebook Audience Network`](https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/news-and-insights/upgrade-requirements) have a policy that ads should cached for 60 minutes or less If any cached ad has shown after 60 minutes will not be considered for revenue generation purposes.

Is there any same kind of policy for Pre-loading interstitial ads in `AdMod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for AdMob ads, but I'd definitely recommend ditching any ad you've held in memory for more than an hour.

Comment: Is it true for AdView too (banner ads of various kinds) ?