# How long can I hold an interstitial loaded ad before showing it?

Tags: java, android, admob

My question is about Google Admob interstitial ads:

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
```

Once I've loaded (properly and according to the documentation) an `IntersitialAd` object (`mInterstitialAd`) I can display the ad by calling the `Show` method as long as `mInterstitialAd != Null`:

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
  mInterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this);
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
}
```

But what happens if it takes me hours to display the ad? Will this still be a valid ad impression even if the `mInterstitialAd != Null` or it expires after some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution in a document about Admob display rate optimization.

Preloaded ads cannot be stored for more than one hour. Impressions recorded with preloaded ads that have been stored for more than an hour are not counted. Ads that are cached for more than an hour must be updated by making a new ad request.

Comment: Mr. Brogdon from flutter team recommend us to store it no more than one hour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871281/pre-loading-interstitial-ads-what-is-the-max-timeminutes-they-can-be-cache-b